# Regarding 3D to 2D conversion of tensor

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have voxelized input of dimension (256,256,256) passed through an encoder of CNN layers and get the output of encoder with dimension (1,497,16,16,16) i.e; (B,C,H,W,D) and now I'm reshaping it directly to (1,497,64,64) to reduce the complexity of the model. This reshaped tensor is passed through flow based generative model. My fundamental doubt is can we directly reshape a 3D data to 2D data and send it as input to flow based generative model? If this cannot be done I would like to know why can't it be done this way and also what would be the procedure that has to be followed.

The problems I have faced by directly reshaping is after certain number of epochs around 35, training loss is going to NAN. Till that point loss was decreasing. There is a possibility of exploding gradient problem. But gradient clipping is already there. So, it might be caused because of direct reshaping. If direct reshaping is possible then there is possibilty for gradient exploding issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm mostly addressing the reshaping component of your question. As for NaNs, you will probably need to spend some time logging and debugging the code to figure out why they are occurring. The [`torch.autograd.detect_anomaly`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.detect_anomaly) context manager may be useful.

As for the resizing, consider the following 16x16 sequence of 16 images:
[image]

Suppose I represent this as a 3x16x16x16 tensor in your format of (C,H,W,D) (though PyTorch [usually assumes](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv3d.html) (C,D,H,W)). If I were to reshape this into an image of shape 3x64x64 (C,H,W) using `Tensor.reshape` or `Tensor.view`, then the resulting image would look like this

[image]

Observe that you lose most of the relationships between neighboring voxels and introduce new spurious relationships. For example, now none of the rows neighbor their original rows. Considering how CNNs operate, these spatial relationships are crucial for the model's performance.

There are a couple of ways you could attempt to deal with this, but based on my experience, there's no single agreed-upon best method.

One way would be to take more care when reshaping the tensor to retain as much information as possible. For example, put it on a grid:

[image]

This still introduces lots of spurious relationships, but at least most of the rows are still associated with their original neighboring rows.

An alternative procedure would be adding additional model components that convert the 497x16x16x16 features to 497x64x64 features.

1. transpose to (C,D,H,W) format
2. reshape to (497*16)x16x16. Basically, this treats each frame/page as a channel. Activations will take into account all frames at the same time, though we still lose the depth-ordering relationships.
3. upsample layers. For example, two `ConvTranspose2d` with 3x3 kernels, stride of 2, and padding of 1. You probably want some additional non-upsampling conv layers in between these, though you would have to experiment.

Of course, there are other options. I guess that the optimal method will be dependent on specific use cases and data.